# How do I get the value of a HTML checkbox input element?

Tags: php

```
    <?php

    include ("database.php");               
    $qry = "Select * from tbnam where $option like '%$content%'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);        
    while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $id=$row['id'];
    ?>
//creating table
    <tr><?echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[]\" id=\"checkbox[]\"  value=\"".$row['id']."\" /></td>";?>
    <td><? echo $row['name'];?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['address'];?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['email'];?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['telephone'];?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['problem'];?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['reply_query'];?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['type'];?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['other'];?></td></tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Print" size="10"/>
    </form>
    </table>
```

how i got the checkbox values? any need of passing $id in checkbox[] array ? if yes how it is possible? help me...name=\"checkbox["\".$id"\"]\"

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow ! Try `var_dump($_POST['checkbox']);`.

Comment: First line: `include` does not need the `()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing

```
<tr><?echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[]\" id=\"checkbox[]\"  value=\"".$row['id']."\" /></td>";?>
```

you have designed a form which returns an array of values with each value corresponding to a checkbox that has been "checked".

In this example the POST variable that points to this array will be $_POST['checkbox']. Since you have set the value of each checkbox as $row['id'], each element in the checkbox array will have the 'id' value corresponding to each checkbox that you have checked.

You can check out these values like this:

```
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $value)
{ 
  echo $value;
}
```

or simply by saying:

```
echo var_dump($_POST['checkbox']);
```

Hope this makes it clear. :)

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST['checkbox']` will give you an array of the value you checked.

Answer (score 0):

What is the need of the array here (checkbox[]) , when you are showing a single checkbox element here.
Also for IDs, we need not to mention as arrays.

You simply use like below

```
<tr><?echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox\"  value=\"".$row['id']."\" /></td>";?>
```

And While reading,

```
if (isset($_POST["checkbox"])) // Returns true if checked
{

}
```

Hope it helps.